# need advice on approach of reading file from the Linux system

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am somewhat new to java and spring.

We have the requirement of reading the file of some thousand records and calling micro service developed in spring boot deployed on PCF.

I have  two approaches in my mind. One is we have simple spring boot application where it reads the file and call required micro service. The other is to develop spring batch with dummy item writer which calls micro service.

Confused which one to choose.  Any advise here will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the outcome of your batch job? What does the API call do? Do you need to write data somewhere after the call or do you need to make some POST/PUT/DELETE request for each item?

Comment: not writing anywhere. once i read the file i call the rest service with the data of record by record. called rest service do the rest of the processing which is already exist and it take care some business processing .  requirement is simple read the file and call the rest service. delete the source file.  expect the input file after every one hour

Comment: Posting/Putting a resource to a REST endpoint can be considered as a write operation IMO, so it can be done in the writer. Otherwise, use a Tasklet instead of a chunk oriented step.

Comment: ok i am going to implement the same. thank you.